# javascript 4dimensional global array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I would like to create the 4-dimensional global array and access it like presented in the code below, but I don't know how to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
var foo = [[],[],[],[]];

foo[1][1][1][1] = 5;
foo[1][1][1][2] = 7;
...
...
...
foo[4][3][2][2] = 11;

function myFunction() {
  var a = foo[3][1][2][1];
}
```

Comment: Your array is two dimensional

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript 4D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053108/javascript-4d-arrays)